# Prove or disprove that $CB=0$ if $C$ row equivalent to $A$ and $AB=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Given that $A_{m \times n}, B_{n \times p}$ are not zero matrices and $AB=0$, $C$ is row equivalent to $A$. Prove or disprove/give an opposing example that $CB=0$.

This seems to be true because if $C$ is row equivalent to $A$ then they have the same canonical/reduced echelon form (which is unique). If we do $AB$ (which is the same as $CB$) even if $A$ is of canonical form we'll still get $0$.  So by that logic $CB=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have come to the correct conclusion (the statement is true), but I don't like your proof.  In particular, your statement

> If we do $AB$ (which is the same as $CB$) even if $A$ is of canonical form we'll still get $0$.  So by that logic $CB=0$.

Is difficult to understand and requires more justification.  Here's what I would say:

> Since $C$ is row-equivalent to $A$, there exists an invertible matrix $R$ such that $C = RA$.  It follows that
>   $$
> CB = (RA)B = R(AB) = R(0) = 0 
> $$

Or alternatively:

> Since $C$ is row-equivalent to $A$, it has the same nullspace as $A$.  Since $AB = 0$, each column of $B$ is in the nullspace of $A$.  It follows that each column of $B$ is in the nullspace of $C$, which means that $CB = 0$.

Comment: But doesn't a matrix have to be a square one to be invertible?

Comment: Yes.  $R$ in this case would be $m \times m$.

Comment: But we're not given that the matrices are square

Comment: I am not saying that $A,B,$ or $C$ are square.  I am saying that there is a square matrix $R$ which encodes the row-operations that take you from $A$ to $C$.

Comment: If there was $D$, a row equivalent matrix to $B$, would $AD=0$ hold as well?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Is there a reason you think this should be the case?

Comment: Wouldn't the same argument hold here as well?

Comment: It would not.  Try to write out the argument, see if you can find where it falls apart in your new case.  A hint: if $D$ were *column-equivalent* to $B$, then we would have $AD = 0$.

Comment: I can't find any counter example to show that $AD$ is not necessarily $0$, do you have any hint for $A$ and $D$?

Comment: I did find an example! $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$,  $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $D=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Great! You might notice that the third column of $A$ and third rows of $B,D$ aren't strictly necessary for the example to work.